# Determine machine epsilon in fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90, epsilon

How can I write a program in FORTRAN 90 that determines the machine epsilon in any computer ?

```
     type ErrorOrT[M[+_], A] = EitherT[M, Throwable, A]
type ErrorOr[A] = ErrorOrT[IO, A]
```

Comment: Is that the Scala language?

Answer (score 10):

You'd read to the back of your favourite Fortran reference where you'd find the intrinsic function `epsilon`

And, if you think the code you've posted is Fortran you've been misled.